# multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions

Sketch the region bounded by the surfaces.
$z=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$  ,z=2

I get $x^2+y^2=z^2/4$ so do I need to insert the z and it will become $x^2+y^2=1$ ? And the graph that
I will get is circle?

Comment: The circle is where the two surfaces intersect.  Your region will be everything below the plane z=2, in shrinking circles down to the origin

Comment: sorry i dont understand. Does it mean I do not need to insert z=2 into the equation z given? So the graph will be the circle and the axis at x and y is 2?

Comment: or the shape of graph is a cone? so at axis z the point is 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the comment into an answer.  Note that $z=2$ is a plane,  it has all points of the form $(x,y,2)$ on it.  Now,  consider $z$ as a parameter on your other surface.  Plugging in, say, z=0 gets you the $0=2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, which has only $(0,0)$ as the solution.  Any $z<0$ has no solution. As z increases, you get bigger and bigger circles.  As you noted $x^2+y^2=z^2/4=(z/2)^2$,  as $z$ increases you get circles of bigger and bigger radii.  Once you hit $z=2$ your growing circles "hits" the plane that bounds it on top and stops.

Comment: Ohhh okay now I understand. Thank you for taking time explaining it for me :)

Comment: No problem. If this answered your question, go ahead and click the check on the answer, this both marks it as answered and rewards a bit of reputation :).